# Autowired applicationContext is null in JUnit 5

Tags: spring, junit5

I'm trying to migrate my spring applications to test with JUnit 5. It worked fine with JUnit 4. My problem is that I can't access the application context, it is null, but should be an object. I've included imports etc, in case something is wrong there.

Test:

```
package com.mycompany.mavenspringjunit5;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;


@SpringJUnitConfig(locations = "/test-config.xml")
public class MainTest
{
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Autowired
    Integer number;

    // fails
    @Test
    public void testGivenAppContext_WhenInjected_ThenItShouldNotBeNull()
    {
        System.out.println("number: " + number);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(applicationContext, "applicationContext should not be null");
    }

    // works
    @Test
    public void testDoStuff()
    {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/test-config.xml");
        Main instance = ctx.getBean(Main.class);
        instance.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Main:

```
package com.mycompany.mavenspringjunit5;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Main
{
    @Autowired
    Integer number;
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        ctx.getBean(Main.class).doStuff();
    }

    void doStuff()
    {
        System.out.println("The number is " + number);
        System.out.println("applicationContext " + applicationContext);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenSpringJunit5</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.version>5.3.4</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

test-config.xml (in the directory "....\MavenSpringJunit5\src\test\resources\test-config.xml"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.mavenspringjunit5"/>

    <bean id="number" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <constructor-arg value="42" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.mycompany.mavenspringjunit5.MainTest
The number is 42
applicationContext org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@51521cc1, started on Mon Feb 22 10:49:15 CET 2021
number: null
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.884 sec <<< FAILURE!
com.mycompany.mavenspringjunit5.MainTest.testGivenAppContext_WhenInjected_ThenItShouldNotBeNull()  Time elapsed: 0.009 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: applicationContext should not be null ==> expected: not <null>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:39)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail(Assertions.java:118)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.failNull(AssertNotNull.java:47)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java:36)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java:292)
    at com.mycompany.mavenspringjunit5.MainTest.testGivenAppContext_WhenInjected_ThenItShouldNotBeNull(MainTest.java:24)
```

Comment: There is no spring extension so it is run with regular Junit5. Hence spring isn't involved currently.

Comment: `SpringJUnitConfig` combines `ExtendWith` and `ContextConfiguration` according to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-junit-config , or do you mean something is missing in pom.xml ?

Comment: Thought only the Spring Boot components extended the `@ExtendWith`. Have you tried `classpath:/test-config.xml` as a `location`. Tip you can remove the `<context:annotation-config />` that is already implied with `<context:component-scan />`.  That and you might want to try the latest final version or JUnit5 instead of a milestone release.

Comment: All tried before (and retried now), except for the last suggestion which I did now, but doesn't help.

Comment: This is actually a maven issue, or rather the `maven-surefire-plugin`. use version 2.22.2 (or the 3.0.0.M5). Tests run fine in your IDE but will fail in your maven build. This is also expressed in the junit5 docs (https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven).

Comment: @M.Deinum My goodness thank you I can go to bed now.

Comment: Technically a `SpringBootTest` is an integration test. So it should be named `MainIT.java` and be executed with the failsafe maven plugin, not surefire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested it and tests run fine in my IDE (Intellij) running the same with your provided `pom.xml` fails.

You need to upgrade the `maven-surefire-plugin` to properly detect and execute the classes.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is also expressed in the Junit5 [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven).

Comment: It turned out that maven (3.6.3) was using 2.12.4 ‍♂️ Thank you

Comment: The Apache Maven team will produce the super pom with updated version of plugins dedicated for the default lifecycle. We wanted to release Maven 3.7.0 but the dvelopment on this version was stopped and a new version 4.0.0 will be release instead.